# Why is Current always null for React.createRef() in react typescript

Tags: reactjs

below is my code and console shows that current is always null and I am not sure why.

```
private tree: any;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tree =  React.createRef()
    this.state = {
//
}

componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.tree);
  }

render(){
return(
<div id= "tree" className="ba-treeview" ref={this.tree}>
//
</div>
)}
```

Comment: There is no problem with your code, the ref is not null see example: https://codesandbox.io/s/class-ref-check-1q4dc

Answer (score 1):

I think there are Syntax issues in your code.

I had tried it on *[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-antonelli-k0cuh)* and it is working fine, though I had made correction to syntax wherever needed. Below is the code for your reference:

**Tree Component:**

```
import React from "react";

class Tree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tree = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      someState: "StateValue"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.tree);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="tree" className="ba-treeview" ref={this.tree}>
        TREE COMPONENT
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default Tree;
```

**Usage (App.js):**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Tree from "./Tree";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Tree />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Below is the screen capture of execution for your reference:

[image]

Hope this may help.

Thanks